# strimzi 0.14: Kafka broker failed authentication

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, strimzi

I tried to build a Kafka cluster using Strimzi (0.14) in a Kubernetes cluster.

I use the examples come with the strimzi, i.e. examples/kafka/kafka-persistent.yaml.

This yaml file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 2.3.0
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
      plain: {}
      tls: {}
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 2
      log.message.format.version: "2.3"
    storage:
      type: jbod
      volumes:
      - id: 0
        type: persistent-claim
        size: 12Gi
        deleteClaim: false
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 3
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 9Gi
      deleteClaim: false
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
```

`kubectl apply -f examples/kafka/kafka-persistent.yaml`

Both zookeepers and kafka brokers were brought up.
However, I saw errors in kafka broker logs:
`[SocketServer brokerId=1] Failed authentication with /10.244.5.94 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-1-ListenerName(REPLICATION)-SSL-0]`

Anyone know how to fix the problem?

Comment: One of the things which can cause this is if your cluster is using different DNS suffix for service domains (default is `cluster-local`). But I would need more logs to confirm it. If it is the case, you need to find out the right suffix and use the environment variable `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_DNS_DOMAIN` in the cluster operator deployment to override the default. If you exec into one of the Kafka or Zookeeper pods and do `hostname -f` it sould show the suffix.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. It is the suffix problem. After rebuilding the cluster operator, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things which can cause this is if your cluster is using different DNS suffix for service domains (default is `.cluster.local`). You need to find out the right DNS suffix and use the environment variable `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_DNS_DOMAIN` in the Strimzi Cluster Operator deployment to override the default value.

If you exec into one of the Kafka or Zookeeper pods and do `hostname -f` it should show you the full hostname from which you can identifythe suffix.

*(I pasted this from comments as a full answer since it helped to solve the question.)*